# Routes that starts with the same prefix as controller not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Why Routes that starts with the same prefix as controller not working? With below code on my controller I am making a get call  where RoutePrefix is same as the controller name. Now I am making a call as something like http://[localhost]/subscribers which is not working.

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
 [RoutePrefix("subscribers")]
 public class SubscribersController : ApiController
 {
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" }.AsQueryable();
    }
 }
}
```

I tried something as Route("~/subscribers") instead of just Route("") but that is not working as well.

The option that is working for me currently is http://[localhost]/subscribers/all with below code

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
 [RoutePrefix("subscribers")]
 public class SubscribersController : ApiController
 {
    [Route("all")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" }.AsQueryable();
    }
 }
}
```

How can I make it work as http://[localhost]/subscribers

Comment: What is "not working"? What do you do, what do you expect, what does happen?

Comment: This works perfectly for me.. what is the http status code you getting ?

Comment: I am getting 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Both samples work just fine. I've created a new web project and added both versions to the project. 
Try to create a sample project and check if problem persists.